# Bundle deal Expedia

Tags: hotels, cancellations

I recently booked a bundle deal of Flight + Hotel on Expedia, which was cheaper than booking the flight and the hotel separately. In this bundle deal, the hotel is booked for a part of my complete itinerary. Due to the change in travel plans, I will be able to take the flight booked in the bundle deal, but I will not be able to show up at the hotel. I have already paid the money for both the flight and the hotel. I read [here](http://www.independenttraveler.com/travel-tips/air-travel/a-clever-secret-to-getting-a-cheaper-airfare) that if I do not show up at the hotel, my entire booking will be voided (please see the second last paragraph of the article). Is that true?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because nobody knows the exact terms and conditions of your particular Expedia contract.

Comment: I would like to know if somebody has a similar past experience.

Comment: I would be surprised if the hotel told the airline (or Expedia) about this. I would be surprised if the airline would consider itself bound by a hotel's word. I think the hotel will pocket the money and keep its mouth shut. To be honest, I know people who use these deals, or more often, the car+flight deals, and I've never heard of anyone losing a flight reservation over it.

Comment: It's not quite clear why would you lose anything if you already paid for the hotel. It's not like they have a problem with people who pay and do not stay. It's different with airlines of course.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your best shot would be to call Expedia and explain your situation to them and ask for a refund. This is of course, subject to the cancelation terms you agreed to when you made the purchase, but I have found Expedia customer service to be very accommodating in the past--they will even speak to the hotel on your behalf. Just be forthright with them, and they will work with you. Even if you don't get a refund, you should be able to keep the rest of your booking (your return flight home). Good luck!

https://gethuman.com/phone-number/Expedia